# WSO2 key manager

Tags: wso2

I am working on implementing API Manager 1.5.0 in a clustered envrionment.  The store and publisher are together on one node, the key manager and gateway clustered on other servers.

We have multiple gateway nodes in a cluster (we don't have an ELB but are using DNS round robin entries to balance between IPs).

When working through the document: http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager
it indicates that "versions above 1.3 should use the same user store and that Governance Registry and Key Manager should be on the same gateway node."  Does it mean logically?  Because I'm planning on having a cluster of servers for Gateway and Key Manager products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to API Manager 1.4.0 the publisher and store could use different user stores. Normally publisher app is used by internal developers of an organisation (due to this the user store being used by publisher can reside in a highly secured network). Since the store app is meant to be used by external users, user store for this can come from a leniently secured network. Multitenancy was introduced in API Manager 1.4.0. If  API Manager is configured to have several tenants, then it's  required to use the same user store for publisher and store. Same is applicable for  registry database. If you are planning to create a multi tenanted APIManager environment, then publisher, store, key manager and gateway should have governance and config mounts created. And the same database should be used as the underlying database.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm planning on having the same store and publisher as internal.  But seperating the gateway and key managers into a clustered farm of servers.  When you say 'goverance and config mounts' I think that is where I run into issues.  I understand pointing everything to a central DB, and that seems to work.  But, once I add the mount configurations the services fail to start citing that they can't create the remote mount and also that there are no open connections in the connection pool.  I will look up the error and post in another comment.